# How to set up background image of the UIView?

Tags: interface-builder, uiimageview

In a case of a custom view, the only way i can think of is to lay an UIImageView on top is it and set it's background to some image.

Can image be overlaid onto the regular UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to place an UIImageView covering whole UIView and arrange it to back in Interface Builder. I think it is the most convenient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add image as background with image pattern. Use the following line of code.

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YouImageName.png"]]];
```

In case you are not applying it to `self.view`, but to some other view in you xib file, then you need to make it `IBOutlet` first.